# Code coverage result show red color for the method name, but the method definition is covered

Tags: karma-jasmine

[image]

While checking code coverage, method name is coming in red. What is the meaning of this. Following is the code

```
fit('set login id', () => {
    spyOn(service, 'setLoginId');
    service.setLoginId('124');
    expect(service.setLoginId).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(service.setLoginId).toHaveBeenCalledWith('124');
  });
```

Comment: did my answer worked ?

Answer (score 0):

because you need to test the condition of assigning `this.loginId` as well something like:

```
it('setLoginId should set loginId',()=>{
    service.setLoginId('id_12');
    expect(service.loginId).toBe('id_12');
})
```